# How to run Postgresql 8.3 Query in Postgresql 9.x Version

Tags: php, postgresql

I have developed our ERP application using PHP 5.2.3 and Postgresql 8.2.3.It works fine ,I would like to upgrade PostgreSql 9.3 but some of the some of the query are not supported in 9.3 Version.My question is why Backward compatibility not supported in new version of postgresql ??? Is there any setting in Postgresql Configuration ???

Please check my below query for Postgresql 8.2.3

```
SELECT #(std.quantity) AS quantity,
       round(std.area,2) AS area,
       std.stock_id,
       COALESCE(selection_value,' ') AS selection_value,
       COALESCE(getorigin_detail(std.stock_id),' ') as origin_desc,
       COALESCE(getlot_ref_no(std.stock_id),' ') as internal_receipt_item_no,
       COALESCE(ma.account_name,' ') AS account_name,
       COALESCE (getbatch_internal_no(std.stock_id),' ') as jcno,
       man.animal_name AS species ,
       COALESCE(buyer_reference||' '||odi.order_id||'-'||odi.item_id,' ') AS buyer_reference,
       sid.shipment_date,
       COALESCE(mm1.company_name,' ') AS customer,
       mm2.company_name AS unit,
       COALESCE(mp.product_desc,' ') AS product_desc,
       COALESCE(odi.colour_name,' ') AS colour,
       COALESCE(odi.thickness,' ') AS thickness,
       odi.size_range AS size,
       odi.internal_order_no AS pono,
       to_char(shipment_time,'HH12:MI:am') AS time
FROM stock_transaction_detail_106 std
   JOIN stock_details_106 sdpc ON std.stock_id=sdpc.stock_id
   JOIN stock_details sd ON std.stock_id=sd.stock_id
   LEFT JOIN master_account ma ON sd.account_id=ma.account_id
   JOIN shipment_items si ON std.reference_detail=si.shipment_item_id
   JOIN shipment_details sid ON si.shipment_id=sid.shipment_id
   JOIN order_details_shipments ods ON si.shipment_item_id=ods.shipment_item_id
   JOIN order_details_items odi ON odi.order_id=ods.order_id AND odi.item_id=ods.item_id
   JOIN order_details od ON odi.order_id=od.order_id
   JOIN relationships r1 ON od.relationship_id=r1.relationship_id
   JOIN master_member mm1 ON r1.partner_id=mm1.member_id
   JOIN relationships r2 ON od.agent_id=r2.relationship_id
   JOIN master_member mm2 ON r2.partner_id=mm2.member_id
   LEFT JOIN sys_master_selection_106 sms106 ON sms106.selection_id = sdpc.selection_id
   JOIN master_product mp ON odi.product_id=mp.product_id
   JOIN master_colour mc ON odi.colour_id=mc.colour_id
   LEFT JOIN master_thickness mt ON mt.thickness_id = odi.thickness_id
   LEFT JOIN master_size ms ON ms.size_id = odi.size_id
   JOIN master_animal man ON man.animal_id=mp.animal_id
WHERE std.reference_detail=80285
  and std.stock_reference_type_id IN (6,21);
```

Comment: It would help if you showed actual queries you perform and the errors you get.

Answer (score 0):

Introduce type casts into your queries if you want to compare numbers and strings.

There is really no excuse for not keeping up to date with a behavior change from almost 10 years ago.

Disabling these automatic type casts was the biggest compatibility break in the recent history of PostgreSQL, but there were some good reasons for it (though I don't know if the developers would have done it if they had known what hardship it would cause).

If you want to continue living with the burden of having to modify each new version of PostgreSQL to which you upgrade, you could use the [script from Peter Eisentraut](http://petereisentraut.blogspot.co.at/2008/03/readding-implicit-casts-in-postgresql.html) to re-introduce the missing type casts. This might cause problems with other applications running against the same database because there will be more ambiguity with function and operator type resolution.

Comment: There are hundreds of query in old version. Is there any possibilities to run the same query in new version ????

Comment: I have added a link to a script that might help you, but I still think it would be better and more future-proof to fix your code.

Comment: And maybe it is better to start by fixing the data types in the DDL. That could reduce the amount of tinkering needed in the code.

Comment: Nice statement. Since you didn't show any error message or table definitions, I guessed that your problem was the one I describe in my answer. I can't say for sure, nor can I say what in particular is wrong with your statement, unless I know at least the error message.

Comment: I getting error as "ERROR:  operator is not unique: text || integer
LINE 3: ...al_name AS species , COALESCE(buyer_reference||' '||odi.orde...
                                                             ^
HINT:  Could not choose a best candidate operator. You might need to add explicit type casts."

Comment: That's what you get from adding all the casts. What is the error message *before* you add the casts?

Comment: I have updated your script "Pg83-implicit-casts.sql" which you provide yesterday.I got the same error message before or after updation of script

Comment: I mean that you should drop all the casts and show the error you get then. Then you could try to add the one cast that remedies the error.

Comment: I have dropped all cast and run my query.Please check the exact error           ERROR:  function pg_catalog.substring(numeric, unknown) does not exist
LINE 1: select substring($1,'-{0,1}[0-9]*[.][0-9]*')::numeric as res...
               ^
HINT:  No function matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.
QUERY:  select substring($1,'-{0,1}[0-9]*[.][0-9]*')::numeric as result
CONTEXT:  PL/pgSQL function format_number(numeric) line 6 at SQL statement
SQL state: 42883

Comment: Try adding only the cast from `numeric` to `text`.

Comment: Thanks the above query working fine when I create above cast,but I have another issue in another query  and its shown an error message as "ERROR:  operator does not exist: integer ~~* unknown
LINE 2: ..._result from order_details_batches where batch_id ilike 'KHA...
                                                             ^
HINT:  No operator matches the given name and argument type(s). You might need to add explicit type casts."

Comment: Sorry forgot to add Query          "select t.q_result from (select batch_id as q_result from order_details_batches where internal_batch_no ilike 'KHAG-44992-1-141' union select batch_id as
q_result from order_details_batches where batch_id ilike 'KHAG-44992-1-141' limit 1) t;"

Comment: Then try adding the cast from `integer` to `text`. The idea is to carefully add individual casts until all your old queries work. Then you can only hope that none of your queries fail because of ambiguities in type resolution. If you cannot find a solution that way, you'll have to rewrite your statements. One more thing: All these casts will be gone again after a major version upgrade.